# Django admin site user password change

Tags: django, django-views

Django admin site used to have a form to change the password for a user that wasn't the logged in user.  You would look at the user's update page, and by the password field, there was a change password link.  You would click it, and it would take you to a different page for changing the password.  I used to take advantage of that page to allow changing of a user's password, without having to open the admin.  In Django 4, it seems to now be missing.  In fact, I can't figure out how one would change a user's password other than their own, without writing my own view.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way in the admin site now to change a different user's password?
2. If this view is gone, what is now the best way for a superuser to have a view that can change passwords for a user?

**Edit:**
This is what I see.  There is no link to change the password where there used to be.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when I am using AbstractBaseUser, and the admin site registration I was using `admin.ModelAdmin` instead of `UserAdmin`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


class EmployeeAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ordering = ['email', ]
    list_display = ['email', ]
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'phone',)}),
        ('Address', {'fields': ('address', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code')}),
        ('Schedule', {'fields': ('time_off',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                    'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        ("User Details", {'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}),
        ("Permission", {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_admin')}),
    )


admin.site.register(get_user_model(), EmployeeAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have checked it right? When you select an user it appears by default in the upper part, just after some semi-blinded parameters of the password.

[image]

Comment: I updated the post with what I see.

Comment: Are you using the built-in user model? It seems you create your own user model called Employee.

Comment: It's an AbstractBaseUser.  I set everything up years ago, using Django 1.11, and it worked fine, but I decided to upgrade the code to use 4.1, and now it doesn't show that field.  I'm not sure what changed in the intervening versions that made it not work.